# How to delete gems periodically from nexus repository

Tags: rubygems, nexus

There are ways to remove old gems from nexus hosted repository periodically? I tried to use scheduled tasks **Remove Releases** and **Remove Snapshots**, but Rubygems repositories are classified as Mixed and Nexus cannot remove in these repositories. Nexus has others ways to do it?

I have a nexus 2.12 installed

Answer (score 0):

Since this is missing for NuGet as well, I found a workaround which may suit for your situtation as well:

It is possible to remove the desired packages on the local file system of the Nexus Server (*[NexusInstallDir]\sonatype-work\nexus\storage\ [FeedName]*) and then reindex the feed.
So it's possible to use a scheduled task of the operating system to cleanup the filesystem and then add a schedule task in Nexus to reindex the feed...